# Perl word frequency counter

Tags: perl

I am trying to make an addition to a word frequency counter I made to take all of STDIN and report to STDOUT each word that appeared in the input and how many times it appeared. I added the -i option and am transliterating all of the letters to lower case before hashing.

The problem I am having is that nothing is being reported to STDOUT and nothing is printing to the command console. It runs without error being produced or given.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @ARGV     = <STDIN>;
my $filename = $ARGV[0];
my $word     = 0;
my %freq     = ();
my @wordarray;

open( FILE, $filename );

while ( <STDIN> ) {

    if ( scalar( @ARGV ) > 1 ) {

        if ( $ARGV[1] eq "-i" ) {

            my $string = $_;
            $string =~ tr/A-Z/a-z/;
            tr/A-Za-z/ /cs;
            my @wordarray = ( split( ' ', lc $string ) );

            foreach my $word ( @wordarray ) {
                $freq{$word}++;
            }
        }
    }

    if ( scalar( @ARGV ) < 2 ) {

        my $string = $_;
        tr/A-Za-z/ /cs;
        my @wordarray = ( split( ' ', $string ) );

        foreach my $word ( @wordarray ) {
            $freq{$word}++;
        }
    }
}

foreach $word ( sort keys %freq ) {
    print "$word $freq{$word}\n";
}

close( FILE );
```

Comment: Please use the help to find out how to format code.

Comment: You really need to learn both how to lay out your code so that it is legible, and to use Stack Overflow's *markdown* to distinguish it as code. You shouldn't just leave a blank line between statements to stop them from wrapping. I've done it for you this time, but please do some reading

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is this line

```
my @ARGV     = <STDIN>;
```

Which defines a lexical array `@ARGV` that is nothing to do with the built-in global variable. And you probably shouldn't be reading into from STDIN at all

Apart from that, it's not clear how you want your program to behave, so I can't offer much more detailed advice